# query to delete if in table one created is older than 31 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables one is `posts` and other one is `recent_viewed` both has date as current_timestamp

(posts) has created

and

(recent_viewed) has date

What I wish is to delete all records from (recent_viewed) by comparing in (posts) table if created date is older than 31 days then delete those postID from recent_viewed table

schema

```
    --
-- Table structure for table `recent_viewed`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `recent_viewed` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `postID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `memberID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `recent_viewed`
--

--
-- Table structure for table `posts`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `postID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`postID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `posts`
--
```

PS: I'm not good at it that is why i am asking for this help would be very thankful to you.

thanks

Comment: Plz provide the schema design to get the better answers.

Comment: hi i have posted in the first post by editing

Comment: try to do a join,i recommend posting some sample data and expected result

Comment: clueless mate thats why i have asked for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an efficient solution, but a simple one which would definitely helps you :

```
delete from recent_viewed where postID in (
select postID from posts where abs(datediff(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,posts.created)) > 31);
```

Comment: thanks alot mate for helping out. really appreciate your kindness